# CMake putting build files in source directory

Tags: cmake

I am very new to CMake. A friend wrote a simple CMakeLists.txt for the project I am coding myself. I am using svn and have just checked out an old version on the same machine into a different folder. Now, in the original source directory (where CMakeLists.txt is located) I create the directory 'build', cd into there, and for the time being run the code

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..
```

This nicely puts all of the files in the build directory

```
-- Build files have been written to: ~/MixedFEMultigrid/build
```

Now when I check out to another directory, create another 'build' directory in that one and then run the CMake command I get the following

```
-- Build files have been written to: ~/oldCode
```

where oldCode is actually the parent directory. I have no idea why this is happening. Can someone explain this to me? The full CMakeLists.txt file is given below,

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (MixedFEMultigrid)
FIND_PACKAGE(LAPACK REQUIRED)
set( SRC_FILES  multigrid.c 
  gridHandling.c
  interpolation.c
  linApprox.c
  params.c
  sparseMatrix.c
  testing.c
  richardsFunctions.c
  definitions.c
  newtonIteration.c
  )

#Adds the executable with all the dependencies
add_executable (multigrid ${SRC_FILES})

#Specifies the libraries to link to the target
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(multigrid ${LAPACK_LIBRARIES} m)

# Update if necessary
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -Wno-long-long -pedantic -fstrict-aliasing -std=c99 -O3")
```

As per the comment by escrafford I am updating to show what I do on the command line.

```
cd ~
mkdir oldCode
cd oldCode
svn co <repository>
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..
```

The build files are then put into the directory 'oldCode' instead of the 'build' directory. The following, on the other hand, puts the build files into the 'build' directory

```
cd ~
mkdir MixedFEMultigrid
cd MixedFEMultigrid
svn co <repository>
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..
```

Comment: did you cd to the build directory in the new project before running cmake? show us exactly what you're typing at the command line.

Comment: Yeah I did. Otherwise it wouldn't have found the CMakeLists.txt file. I've updated the post to include the shell commands I run

Comment: I used your CMakeLists.txt (modified to only have one source file for easier repro), and dir a mkdir build;cd build; cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..  - it works as expected, placing build files under build. Maybe something extra is checked into svn? Everything listed in your question should behave the way you expected it to.

Comment: OK. Thanks for having tried this out. I have had a bit more of a play and have found out what was going wrong. I had inadvertantly run cmake from the source directory which created a CMakeCache.txt file with the source directory as the build directory. This was still being read when I created a build directory, so the build files were still being put into the source directory. Your comments were very useful, thank you

Comment: driving me batty, that was it, if there's an old cmakecache that will override what you want it to do.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That comes from a in-source cmake execution

Remember to remove cmake cache:

```
$ rm CMakeCache.txt
$ mkdir debug
$ cd debug
$ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..
```

That has another benefit, given that cmake do not provide a clean target

```
$ cd ..
$ rm -rf debug
```

is the equivalent of `make clean` or more precisely `make distclean`